# Utilizacion de app.component dependiendo si es usuario o anonimo?

Tags: angular, angular5

Estoy empezando con angular y me surge la siguiente cuestión.

En el componente app.component.html es donde tengo creada una navbar y algunos elementos mas html que es comunes a todas las rutas. Pero ahora quiero crear una parte de administrador que no tiene que utilizar ni la navbar ni los demas elementos. Sino otros que he creado.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo crear otro archivo tipo "app.component" para la parte de administracion con su propia estructura y que no tenga nada que ver con la otra parte?

Comment: De poder de se puede, pero si explicaras un ejemplo mas concreto de lo que necesitas quizas podiera ayudarte.

Comment: @Einer buenas, gracias por contestar, a ver: Estoy creando una parte de administrador de la app web que no tiene nada que ver ni en estilo ni en estructura con las demás paginas,que son las que se llaman desde app.component con su respectiva ruta. Lo que quiero es tener otro app.compoenent donde poner por ejemplo la sidebar de la parte de administrador etc. No se si me he explicado bien